# How to add widget fields based on 3rd party API response?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

In a special case I need a widget which has an additional field based on a 3rd party API response. Now, the problem is that I have to await for the API request to give a response and the beforeConstruct also becomes async and the consequence is that the constructor fill run and terminate earlier than the beforeConstruct and in the admin panel the new field isn't visible.

```
const request = require( 'request-promise' );

module.exports = {
    extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',
    label: 'Widget name',

    beforeConstruct: async function( self, options )
    {
        var fields = [];
        var arrangements = [];
        var optionalFields =
        {
            name: 'optionalFields',
            label: 'Optional Fields',
            fields: []
        };

        const apiResponse = await request( {
            method: 'POST',
            body: {
                // criteria for search
            },
            uri: API_ENDPOINT,
            json: true
        } );

        var newField =
        {
            name: apiResponse.fieldName,
            label: apiResponse.fieldName,
            type: 'string',
        };
        fields.push( contact );
        optionalFields.fields.push( apiResponse.fieldName );
        arrangements.push( optionalFields );

        options.addFields = fields.concat( options.addFields || [] );
        options.arrangeFields = arrangements.concat( options.arrangeFields || [] );
    }
};
```

Do you have any ideas how to wait for beforeConstruct to finish no matter what?

And another question (writing it here because basically it is the same issue): if I have to add new fields to the widget based on a database piece-type collection: 
`await self.apos.docs.getManager( 'optionals' ).find( req, {}, { trash: false } ).toArray();`
can I get somehow the values from DB synchronously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Apostrophe 2.x, for legacy reasons you must use callbacks if you want `beforeConstruct`, `construct` or `afterConstruct` to wait for asynchronous work to be done. But you can still use `async/await` internally; just be sure to `try/catch` and handle the callback appropriately:

```
beforeConstruct: async function(self, options, callback) {
  try {
    const info = await someApiCallHere();
    options.addFields = [ ... use info here ... ];
    return callback(null);
  } catch (e) {
    return callback(e);
  }
}
```

In Apostrophe 3.x, there will be support for just using an `async` function without a callback.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Perfect! And also thanks for the quick and precise answers, always.